# Revising a PS installed programs retrieval script to show PC names

Tags: registry, powershell-3.0, administration

I've been writing a script to let me know what programs people have installed on their computers that I'm not "cool" with. To accomplish this, im using this code:

```
$allowed = @"
Microsoft Office Shared 64-bit Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2016
64 Bit HP CIO Components Installer
Dolby Digital Plus Home Theater
Intel(R) Chipset Device Software
Intel(R) Management Engine Components
...
NVIDIA Install Application
NVIDIA nView 148.47
NVIDIA WMI 2.29.0
Symantec Endpoint Protection
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$path = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

(Get-ChildItem -Path $path | 
    Get-ItemProperty -Name DisplayName -EA SilentlyContinue).DisplayName |
    Where-Object {$_ -notin $allowed} | Sort | Out-File '"path"' -Width 60
```

and running it as a logon script from the domain controller.

It does work, and it works very well indeed. However, it doesn't show me which computer name it took the information from, so I just have a long list of programs, but I don't know what computer they are installed at.

Comment: Include `$env:COMPUTERNAME` in the output filename or write it to the output file. Generally, if you have a logon script write output to a share I'd recommend using the computername in the filename, because that a) allows you to identify where the file came from, and b) avoid concurrency issues when writing to the file.

Comment: sorry, i really am VERY new to powershell, and i dont know that cmdlet. where do i add it and how does it affect the script?

Comment: It's not a cmdlet, it's the PowerShell representation of the `%COMPUTERNAME%` environment variable.

Comment: ahhhhh, alright... i researched it a bit, and managed to get it to work however, now it will make a lot of files, each containing only the programs from one computer, instead of one file that will contain a list of computers and programs per computer... is there an elegant way to make it work in the "single file" format?

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question. As for merging the individual files, you could do something like this: `ls 'C:\some\folder' | % { $_.BaseName; cat $_.FullName } > 'C:\merged.txt'`